# How can extract the list of genes name from the raw data in GEO?

Tags: r, microarray, phylogenetics, data-download

The format of the raw data that upload in GEO is different, like TXT, CEL or other form. How can I extract the **list of genes name** from these formats? And then how can I normalize them with R?

I would be really glad if anyone write **step by step** a complete set of codes for R with an example.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from @benn, converted from comments:*

You can find a step by step description in the [limma user's guide](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf). Just download the CEL files, and follow the user guide.

*[please edit to improve this answer, if possible]*